# redirect file operation to log file in java

Tags: java

I am writing simple Java code to take file which will have 16 records and each record will have 6 fields comma separated.

I am writing code to redirect it to new log file which I am creating but the log files are getting generated empty. Below is my code.

```
try 
{
    String s = "";
    FileReader f  = new FileReader ("C:\\file.txt");
    File log_file = new File ("C:\\file_log.txt");
    BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader(f);
    while((s = sr.readLine()) != null)
    {    
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(log_file);
        PrintStream console = System.out;
        System.setOut(p);
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("check file is present in location");
}
```

Comment: so you basically want to copy the file? or do you want to process it as well?

Comment: I don't see you printing any content from the file to your logfile

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes , i will process later but , once whatever data i want to print in log should have printed . what i need to do here to get console output redirect to log file which i have generated .

Comment: @AdriaanKoster yes maybe , how i can achive same , do i need to pass variable to Printstream or Printwriter

Answer (score 0):

On your code there is nothing that write on log_file.

Try with this:

```
    System.out.println("----------------");
    try {
        String s = "";
        FileReader f = new FileReader("input.txt");
        File Log_file = new File("log.txt");
        BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader(f);
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(Log_file);
        while ((s = sr.readLine()) != null) {
            // write to log
            p.println(s);
            // write to console
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("----------------");
```

Comment: Please, if your question has been answered, consider to flag it as solved.

Comment: checked there is no flag to close this question in 1 shot

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class FileLog {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("output.txt")));

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Put a file called 'input.txt' in your project root directory, containing some lines of text, and run the code.